# Cannot login in expo react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I am trying to publish my react native expo app. So what I tried is to use the command `exp login` but what I get is

```
Input is required, but exp is in non-interactive mode.
Required input:
> Username/Email Address:
```

And exiting from progress. I am trying to run this command in windows 8 machine. I can't find any solutions for so long.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try as follows:

```
expo login -u YOUR-USERNAME-OR-EMAIL -p YOUR-PASSWORD
```

I had logged in successfully and the screenshot as follows.
[run 'expo login' successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap2Op.png)

`expo login -h` or `expo -h` for more details.

Wish it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

With the new local version of the expo cli, this now becomes:

```
npx expo login -u YOUR_USERNAME -p YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Also see: https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue. I was always working in an ios folder, copied it and started working on android. Wanted to build android but had this error.

Deleting my lock file, installing it again and running expo again fixed the error and i could login.